# How to nicely generate a graph of a function of two variables with a restriction on the domain?

Tags: javascript, 3d, processing, p5.js

I recently got into p5 from watching The Coding Train, and I wish to generate two-dimensional surfaces in 3D (like using WEBGL) given by a function of two variables.
If there is a function in Processing that does the job and I’m not just seeing it, then this is a Processing question. Otherwise, this could be a general question on graphing algorithms. I have no background in CS or algorithms.
My first goal is to render a surface z = x^2 + y^2 only for z <= 50.

Here is my initial attempt:

```js
var angleSliderX;
var contour = [];
var cols = 10;
var rows = 10
var d = 10;

function f(x, y) {
    return x**2 + y**2;
}

for (i=0; i<cols; i++) {
    contour.push([]);
    for (j=0; j<rows; j++) {
        contour[i].push(f(i, j));
    }
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400, WEBGL);
    angleSliderX = createSlider(-PI/2, PI/2, PI/4, 0.01);
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    rotateX(angleSliderX.value());

    noFill();
    for (j=0; j<rows-1; j++) {
        for (i=0; i<cols-1; i++) {
            if (contour[i][j] < 50) {
                beginShape()
                vertex(i*d, j*d, contour[i][j]);
                vertex((i+1)*d, j*d, contour[i+1][j]);
                vertex((i+1)*d, (j+1)*d, contour[i+1][j+1]);
                vertex(i*d, (j+1)*d, contour[i][j+1]);
                endShape(CLOSE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I’m concerned that this creates jagged boundaries which I’m not so happy with. Are there known best practices to deal with such concerns without consuming too much computing power? Ideally, I wish to have a flat cut-out at z = 50 of the surface.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You could check if the contour point is within a certain distance above 50, if it is; flat it out, move it down to 50. That could smooth things out but I'm not sure that's the behaviour you are after.